# What happens to an ENS domain NFT in my wallet after its expire date + grace period If I don't renew it?

Tags: nft, ens

What happens to an ENS domain NFT in my wallet after its expire date + grace period If I don't renew it? Will it be still be in the wallet or will it self-destruct?